# Reducing Redundant Queries in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET (vb.net rather than c#) website with a large number of individual pages. To cut down on duplicated code, I have the site's main template as a master page.

There is a particular variable (let's call it Sale) which is used in every single page AND the master page.

At the moment, I've got a simple SQL query in every page AND in the master page that runs each time the page is loaded to check what the value of Sale is (either a 1 or a 0) and, depending on that value different sections of code display.

My problem is that this seems (to me) like a lot of redundant/duplicate SQL calls.

I could write the value of Sale to a session variable, but for a whole bunch of reasons this isn't really practical, so what other options are open to me?

Comment: You can create a control with the code that you are duplicating on each page and use the control in pages that you need the code to be executed!!!

Comment: Ye-es, I can do that, but the control would still be called in both page and master page and it's that redundancy I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: I thought even if it is same code, it perform differently depends on the page you are in..

Comment: You need to cache the value - the caching store would depend upon the semantics - for example, if it's user specific and unlikely to change then session can be good choice. In any case, you can cache it in ASP.NET cache with relevant expiry time!

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, session objects would be a solution but won't work in this case - the main reason being that the value of Sale could change between page views. I suspect caching is also not the solution (for the same reason), but I'm still looking into that.

Comment: Having now finished my research, a cache variable with a short expiry looks like my best bet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net provides a very good caching mechanism. This will allow you to cache any objects you want.

This topic is rather vast, so I will only give you a few pointers:

[Caching Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Adding items to cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx)

Since you are looking to optimize your queries look at [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for these links; interesting reading and it does give me an idea of how to resolve my immediate issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is same for every instance,

Maintain a public static object in your site and save your data in that static variable
on `Application_Start` event of `global.asax` file, that static object would be accessible at each page and master page too,

But beware of demerits of using static objects, for more on that [Go here](http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2009/01/static-variables-and-their-implications.html)

Comment: Having read the demerits, this is definitely not an alley I want to go down, but thanks for the suggestion!